# Can I run current script or a script in ViM?

Tags: vim, scripting

I am developing a php application using ViM. Is there a shortcut for me to run the `currentEditing.php`? Alternatively, is there a shortcut for running `main.php`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can execute shell commands in ViM using the following syntax:

```
:!command -options arguments
```

Therefore, you need to save your file first, and then run whatever command you need for executing php.

I don't know php, so let me give you an example with compiling a C file:

```
... editing text
:w main.c                 # save to file
:!gcc -Wall main.c        # compile the code
:!./a.out                 # execute the executable
```

Note that `:!` commands are run by shell and ViM has no understanding of it. Therefore, you can execute *any* command. This also means that the command cannot run on a modified, unsaved buffer.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your platform, certainly, but when I'm developing python I often run the current script just by executing `:!%`.  The colon for a command (obviously), the bang for shell execute, and the percent for the current filename.